# Angular/TypeScript - map received API-data from multiple tables

Tags: angular, typescript, api, asp.net-core, get

i created my backend and the api-controllers are working fine.
In the frontend, i already created the models for my application:

book.model.ts

```
export class Book {
id : number;
autor: string;
title: string;
returnDate: Date;
numberOfExtensions: number;
cardId:number;
card?: Card;
status?:string;
}
```

card.model.ts

```
export class Card {
id : number;
validityDate: Date;
locked: boolean;
userId: number;
user?: User;}
```

and user.model.ts

```
export class User {
id : number;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
balance: number;}
```

In the frontend service, i GET the data from api with the following:

```
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  readonly baseURL = "https://localhost:44302/api";
  books: Book[];
  users: User[];
  cards: Card[];
  postId: number;

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  async getBooks() {
    await this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/books')
      .toPromise()
      .then(result => this.books = result as Book[]);
  }
  async getCards() {
    await this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/cards')
      .toPromise()
      .then(result => this.cards = result as Card[]);
  }
  async getUsers() {
    await this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/users')
     .toPromise()
      .then(result => this.users = result as User[]);
  }
  async getData() {
    await this.getBooks();
    await this.getCards();
    await this.getUsers();
  }
```

Is it best practice to receive all SQL data first?

Next step is mapping.
For Example for each book, i want to save the card with the fitting ID (Pseudocode):

```
book.card = card where book.cardId === card.id
```

and for every card i want the owner-user of the card:

```
card.user = user where card.userId === user.id
```

I would appreciate any help!
thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `forkJoin`. This will be fired when all the observables are completed. You can manipulate your data after all the downloads are completed.

```
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  readonly baseURL = "https://localhost:44302/api";
  books: Book[];
  users: User[];
  cards: Card[];
  postId: number;

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  getBooks() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/books');
  }
  getCards() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/cards');
  }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/users');
  }
  getData() {
    const observableList: Observable<any>[] = [];
    
    observableList.push(getBooks());
    observableList.push(getUsers());
    observableList.push(getCards());
    
    forkJoin(observableList).subscribe(resultList => {
      this.books = resultList[0] as Book[];
      this.users = resultList[1] as User[];
      this.cards = resultList[2] as Card[];
      
      // Do "book.card = card where book.cardId === card.id"
      const cardMap: Map<number, Card> = new Map();
      for (const card of this.cards) {
        cardMap.set(card.id, card);
      }
      for (const book of this books) {
        const card = cardMap.get(book.cardId);
        book.card = card;
      }
      
      // Do "card.user = user where card.userId === user.id"
      const userMap: Map<number, User> = new Map();
      for (const user of this.users) {
        userMap.set(user.id, user);
      }
      for (const card of this.cards) {
        const user = userMap.get(card.userId);
        card.user = user;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks for you answer, thats awesome! And how would you apply this conditional mapping you wrote in grey? Thanks alot!

Comment: my approach would be something like:

this.books.forEach(b => {
b.card = this.cards.filter(c => c.id === b.cardId)[0];
}

Would that be the correct approach?

Comment: An efficient way is to use `Map`. Your approach needs O(n^2). By using `Map` it will be O(n). I have updated my answer.

Comment: one more question, if i call the above in my component like "this.dataService.getData();" and then i try to use or display the data in my component i created a local array and said:
books: Book[];
books = this.dataService.books;

but it keeps telling me the data is undefined, even though the data gets received in the network tab

Comment: In the components i no longer work with my arrays, but with my maps right?

Comment: It is another question. I recommend you to post a new question.